# Django Custom Decorator - Attribute Error

Tags: python, django, python-decorators

Wrote my own decorator, that get the available reports for a user, and check if the view is within those available reports.

Here's my decorator:

```
from functools import wraps
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden


def can_access(a=None):
    def _can_access(view_func):
        def access(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if not request.user.get_reports().filter(codename=a).exists():
                return HttpResponseForbidden()
            return view_func(request, *args, *kwargs)
        return wraps(view_func)(access)
    return _can_access
```

Gives me this error:

'function' object has no attribute 'status_code'

views.py

```
    import json

from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest

from reporting.enums import ReportFrequency
from base.helpers import get_begin_of_day, get_end_of_day
from billing.helpers import get_fake_usage_by_type, update_license_usage_data
from billing.helpers import get_fake_usage_of_ports, get_fake_usage_by_type, update_license_usage_data, \
    get_usage_by_type, get_fake_minutes_use_by_type
from reporting.enums import ReportFrequency
from .forms import UsageByTypeForm, LAST_MONTH
from reporting.decorators import can_access

@login_required
@can_access
def view_update_license_usage_data(request):
    update_license_usage_data()
    return HttpResponse()


@login_required
@can_access
def billing_home(request):

    return render(
        request,
        'billing_list.html',
        {'section': 'billing_index',}
    )


@login_required
@can_access
def usage_by_type(request):
    user = request.user
    client = user.client

    form = UsageByTypeForm(
        data=request.GET or None,
        user=request.user,
        initial={
            'frequency': ReportFrequency.MONTHLY,
            'begin': (datetime.now()-timedelta(days=365)).date(),
            'end': datetime.now().date()
        }
    )

    return render(
        request,
        'usage_by_type_of_source.html',
        {'form': form}
    )


@login_required
@can_access
def fake_usage_by_type_json(request):
    form = UsageByTypeForm(
        data=request.GET,
        user=request.user,
        initial = {
            'begin': datetime.now()-timedelta(days=365),
            'end': datetime.now()
        }
    )
    form.is_valid()
    data = get_fake_usage_by_type(
        request=request,
        data=form.cleaned_data,
    )
    return JsonResponse(data=data, safe=False)


@login_required
@can_access
def usage_by_type_json(request):
    user = request.user
    form = UsageByTypeForm(
        data=request.GET,
        user=user,
    )
    if not form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('Bad request')

    begin = get_begin_of_day(form.cleaned_data['begin'])
    end = get_end_of_day(form.cleaned_data['end'])
    clients = form.cleaned_data.get('clients', [])
    mcus = form.cleaned_data.get('mcus', [])
    data = get_usage_by_type(
        user=request.user,
        begin=user.get_utc_time(begin),
        end=user.get_utc_time(end),
        freq=form.cleaned_data['frequency'],
        client_ids=clients,
        mcu_ids=mcus,
    )
    return JsonResponse(data=data, safe=False)


@login_required
@can_access
def usage_of_ports(request):
    user = request.user
    client = user.client

    form = UsageByTypeForm(
        data=request.GET or None,
        user=request.user,
        initial={
            'frequency': ReportFrequency.MONTHLY,
            'begin': (datetime.now()-timedelta(days=365)).date(),
            'end': datetime.now().date()
        }
    )

    return render(
        request,
        'usage_of_ports.html',
        {'form': form}
    )


@login_required
@can_access
def fake_usage_of_ports_json(request):
    form = UsageByTypeForm(
        data=request.GET,
        user=request.user,
        initial = {
            'begin': datetime.now()-timedelta(days=365),
            'end': datetime.now()
        }
    )
    form.is_valid()
    data = get_fake_usage_of_ports(
        request=request,
        data=form.cleaned_data,
    )
    return JsonResponse(data=data, safe=False)


@login_required
@can_access
def usage_of_ports_json(request):
    form = UsageByTypeForm(
        data=request.GET,
        user=request.user,
    )
    if not form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('Bad request')

    data = get_usage_by_type(
        user=request.user,
        begin=form.cleaned_data['begin'],
        end=form.cleaned_data['end'],
        client_ids=form.cleaned_data['clients'],
        mcu_ids=form.cleaned_data['mcus'],
        types=None,
    )
    return JsonResponse(data=data, safe=False)


@login_required
@can_access
def minutes_use_by_type(request):
    user = request.user
    client = user.client

    form = UsageByTypeForm(
        data=request.GET or None,
        user=request.user,
        initial={
            'frequency': ReportFrequency.MONTHLY,
            'begin': (datetime.now()-timedelta(days=365)).date(),
            'end': datetime.now().date()
        }
    )

    return render(
        request,
        'minute_use_by_type.html',
        {'form': form}
    )


"""@login_required
@can_access
def minutes_use_by_type_json(request):
    form = UsageByTypeForm(
        data=request.GET,
        user=request.user,
    )
    if not form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('Bad request')

    data = get_minutes_use_by_type(
        user=request.user,
        begin=form.cleaned_data['begin'],
        end=form.cleaned_data['end'],
        client_ids=form.cleaned_data['clients'],
        mcu_ids=form.cleaned_data['mcus'],
        types=None,
    )
    return JsonResponse(data=data, safe=False)"""


@login_required
@can_access
def fake_minutes_use_by_type_json(request):
    form = UsageByTypeForm(
        data=request.GET,
        user=request.user,
        initial = {
            'begin': datetime.now()-timedelta(days=365),
            'end': datetime.now()
        }
    )
    form.is_valid()
    data = get_fake_minutes_use_by_type(
        request=request,
        data=form.cleaned_data,
    )
    return JsonResponse(data=data, safe=False)
```

The decorator is in another app (reporting)

What is happening and how to solve it??

PD. I the views of the same app (reporting) it works no problem.

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/latin/Documents/booking_center/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  223.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "/Users/latin/Documents/booking_center/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/middleware/locale.py" in process_response
  39.         if (response.status_code == 404 and not language_from_path

Exception Type: AttributeError at /reports/billing/time_usage_per_licence/
Exception Value: 'function' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

Comment: Please post the (relevant parts of the) traceback.

Comment: You should decorate it with `@can_access()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You decorate it the wrong way. You should decorate the functions **with a call to `can_access(..)`**, like:

```
@login_required
@can_access()  # with brackets
def view_update_license_usage_data(request):
    # ...
    pass

@login_required
@can_access(a='some_a_value')  # with brackets
def billing_home(request):
    # ...
    pass
```

(also applied to other view functions).

This should happen since `can_access` itself is in fact *not* a decorator function. The `can_access` is a *factory* that *produces* a decorator function. Indeed:

```
def can_access(a=None):  # function producing the decorator
    def _can_access(view_func):  # the actual decorator
        def access(request, *args, **kwargs):  # the new (decorated) function
            if not request.user.get_reports().filter(codename=a).exists():
                return HttpResponseForbidden()
            return view_func(request, *args, *kwargs)
        return wraps(view_func)(access)  # return (decorated) function
    return _can_access # return *decorator
```

If we thus do *not* use brackets in the decorator statement, Python will decorate the `view` with `can_access` itself. Hence `a=view_update_license_usage_data`, and the "*decorated*" function is then `_can_access(view_func)`.

As a result the `request` object will thus get passed through the `view_func` parameter. This "view" will not return a `HttpResponse`, but a function (the `access(..)` function), and this function has no `status_code`, hence Django will fail to actually produce a HTTP response, since it does not know what to fill in as status, message, etc.

And since we are all into decorating, it is usually better to decorate the decorated function with a `@wraps` decorator as well:

```
def can_access(a=None):  # function producing the decorator
    def _can_access(view_func):  # the actual decorator
        @wraps(view_func)
        def access(request, *args, **kwargs):  # the new (decorated) function
            if not request.user.get_reports().filter(codename=a).exists():
                return HttpResponseForbidden()
            return view_func(request, *args, *kwargs)
        return access  # return (decorated) function
    return _can_access # return *decorator
```

Comment: At the end it was @can_access(codename_of_report), but your comment made me get it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GuillermoGonzalez: yeah, the idea is that you call it with the parameter `a`, or if you leave it blank, `None` is used. But I will update the answer to make that more clear.